# Conditionally adapt a function of one argument to take two

Tags: python, python-3.x

At some point I have a user-supplied function which *either* takes 1 or 2 arguments. I want to call it with two arguments, and in the case it only takes one, the second argument should be ignored.

How can I conditionally adapt this function, or otherwise call it so that the unexpected second argument is simply dropped?

```py
def call(f):
    # f might take 1 or 2 arguments, if it takes 2 I should call it like
    f(1, 2)
    # otherwise it should be called like
    f(1)
```

Is there some way better than explicitly examining the number of arguments e.g., with `signature`?

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but if you have access to the lambda function definition you could add a second optional argument to the functions that take only 1 argument, ignore it in the definition and call every function with 2 arguments. E.g. if you have `l = lambda x: x+2` you can write it as `l=lambda x, y=0: x+2`.

Comment: @gionni - right, in this case I can't modify the lambdas: they are many and outside my control. I can only control the call site.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it couldn't be that simple :-(. Not exactly a better solution, but for the sake of readability, I think using a try - except block might be easier.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - yes, it could be any function. In my case they happen to be lambdas, which is why I framed the question that way. Perhaps it would be better to make it more generic.

Answer (score 1):

The only work around I see here is using `try/except` to catch a `TypeError` that is raised by a call with the wrong number of arguments.

If you are concerned with performance, be aware that this solution is very inefficient... Probably you should overload the parent ("wrapper") function that would be calling `call`, such that the parent function already knows whether to call `f` with 1 or 2 arguments

```
def call(f):
    try:
        # f might take 1 or 2 arguments, if it takes 2 I should call it like
        f(1, 2)
    except TypeError:
        # otherwise it should be called like
        f(1)
```

Comment: Why do you say this is very inefficient? The first function is not even called in the case of a single argument. The exception is raised at the attempt to call the function and then the second one is called

Comment: Because the try statement is not efficient if you are looking for fast code... Even some if...else would be either more efficient or comparable to try...except... I code scientific simulations, and I always avoid if...else whenever possible

Comment: Well of course it is not *as efficient* as no conditions, but what I mean is that I doubt it creates a bottleneck or a real issue. Anyway I believe this is *the* solution for this problem, so +1...

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it with two, catch the exception that occurs if it doesn’t take two, call it with one in the except clause.